# Create Project PHP Example using XTFR webservice API

Tags: xtrf

Can anyone please help me with create project example using XTRF webservice API. Thanks in advance.

-Vamsi

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to create a project in [Usage Examples](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS/Usage+Examples) section of the documentation for [WebService API](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS). I also suggest reading [reference documentation](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWS/API+Reference) for the individual methods and types used across the example code.